# Ruby DSL define_method with arguments

Tags: ruby, dsl

This is what I'm looking to do.

```
# DSL Commands
command :foo, :name, :age
command :bar, :name

# Defines methods
def foo(name, age)
  # Do something
end

def bar(name)
  # Do something
end
```

Basically, I need a way to handle arguments through `define_method`, but I want a defined number of arguments instead of an arg array (i.e. `*args`)

This is what I have so far

```
def command(method, *args)
  define_method(method) do |*args|
    # Do something
  end
end

# Which would produce
def foo(*args)
  # Do something
end

def bar(*args)
  # Do something
end
```

Thoughts?

Comment: I don't understand `but I want a defined number of arguments instead of an arg array (i.e. *args)` - any example for this...

Comment: See updated question. Added examples under what I have.

Comment: what's the issue with your one ?

Comment: I would prefer to limit the number of arguments so I know exactly how many to call.

Comment: your post is not clear..sorry :)

Comment: I don't understand how your `command` works. How is the method body passed to the definition? The variable names go hand in hand with the variables used in the method definition. It does not make sense to specify the form of the arguments without having the method body.

Comment: @JohnLedbetter And for some reason that's the words which weren't coming out of my mouth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best workaround for this would be do to something like the following:

```
def command(method, *names)
  count = names.length
  define_method(method) do |*args|

    raise ArgumentError.new(
      "wrong number of arguments (#{args.length} for #{count})"
    ) unless args.length == count

    # Do something
  end
end
```

Comment: I half like this, half don't. Let me think about it. :)

Answer (score 3):

It's a little weird, but you can use some type of `eval`. `instance_eval`, `module_eval` or `class_eval` could be used for that purpose, depending on context. Something like that:

```
def command(method, *args)
  instance_eval <<-EOS, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
    def #{method}(#{args.join(', ')})
      # method body
    end
  EOS
end
```

This way you'll get exact number of arguments for each method. And yes, it may be a bit weirder than 'a little'.

Comment: Beautiful hack :)